# Does a wildcard inside double-quotes glob?

Tags: bash, globbing

On a "standard BASH" does a wildcard inside double-quotes glob? For example:

```
$ touch abc
$ ls "*abc*"
```

would that, or wouldn't that work on bash?

I was told Ubuntu shipped with a bash variant that doesn't conform to POSIX or BASH.  Is that true?

Comment: Which question would you like answered first?

Comment: ...................Both

Comment: For the record, it is better to ask one question at a time (maybe that's what Ignacio meant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer from man bash:

Enclosing  characters  in  double  quotes  preserves  the  literal  value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \

So:

```
~$ touch sas
~$ ls *a*
sas
~$ ls "*a*"
ls: cannot access *a*: No such file or directory
```

Of course when talking about double quotes and asterisks there is another exception: parameter expansion (ie: "$*") ...but that's another history

For the second question: are you asking about dash? dash is a lightweight shell for scripts. In debian, and in ubuntu per extension (as is debian based), is aliased to sh; It's major advantage over bash is its speed, so it is used by default for system scripts; however bash is still available as the interactive shell for users by default

```
 ~$ ls -l /bin/sh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2011-04-21 11:54 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Comment: Ah.. Thanks.  Yes, I was aware /bin/sh was aliased to `dash`.  But anyway, someone I am talking to tells me this works on his Red Hat system [* globs when double quoted--he says the only way to be sure they do not glob is to use single quotes].  Any idea why?

Comment: No, your friend is completely wrong - double check the quote from man bash I've posted in my answer.

Comment: I did not say he was my friend :P  We were having a disagreement, and him being a "programmer for 11 years" and has a big job, and me who's just been learning from google and stuff, since I disagreed with him, this other person [who is a friend's friend --this other guy was his friend] started talking about how I should not be brushing aside his knowledge, because he, by far, was the most knowledgeable one in the discussion.  
But thanks! :)